# Expand div on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container_he">
    <div class="header_he"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content_he">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".header_he").click(function () {

    $header_he = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content_he = $header_he.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content_he.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header_he.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content_he.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.container_he {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container_he div {
    width:100%;
}
.container_he .header_he {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container_he .content_he {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

There it works perfectly. But when I wanted to launch in my website it won't expand to any click on it.

Here is my website link. http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/en/products

What could cause this error ? Some other div elements prevent from expanding? 
Thanks

Comment: Missing DOM-ready? `$(function(){/*Your Code*/});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/2155/ as Anton said. $(function(){ at beginning

and }); at end

Comment: YOu have <head> and <body> tags repeating in your website...fix that...might fix this also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to include the fancybox and application script at the top of your page and as you haven't included jQuery Library before this it is crashing the scripts and therefore nothing will work.

You need to add the following to your page before the other 2 scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A good tip would be to use a decent browser like chrome and press f12.  You will be able to access the js console and it will give you a list of any errors that are occuring

Answer (score 2):

First fix your fancybox error - TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function. This might also cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have found $(...).fancybox is not a function  when viewing your site. That causes script to break